# Al hacer doble clic en el icono se cierra la ventana Python

Tags: python

mi problema es el siguiente, he hecho un navegador en Python con el siguiente código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Prueba')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon/ico.ico"))
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Esto me abre el navegador sin problemas, salvo que no muestra el icono y además cuando hago clic doble clic sobre el icono por defecto la ventana se me cierra, como puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: No estoy seguro que sea la solución pero y ¿si le intentas colocar un mainloop o algo parecido? porque cuando yo utilizo la librería tkinter e hice una vista del arbol y me di cuenta para que me aparezca el icono tenía que colocar un mainloop sino nada.